# Android app compiles and installs, but won't show up in my apps

Tags: android

Has anyone seen an issue where you can export your app to an .apk file and you can install it and everything looks ok but the app never shows up in the list of installed applications.  I have another app that installed and is running fine.  Totally stumped by what I could be doing wrong... I think it's signed correctly (I've tested the key on the working app... am I missing something really stupid?)

EDIT
I'm editing to add the solution. 
Android requires that the main Activity be called MAIN in the manifest. You can call your class anything you want but the XML has to include this:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Not realizing this, I had named mine something else and rather than just failing outright, it worked perfectly in the emulator, but failed to open on the phone.

Comment: I have a widget that works during development in both emulator and phone. After I upload it to market, and I install it, it is not showing up in the widget list. I then rebuild, re-upload, and then it works; but a few comments from my 'downloaders' said it is not showing up.

Comment: Because they installed the app to SD.

Comment: but I'm not installing it to SD. I'm just installing it via ADB and via download.  But it's only available to be uninstalled. It never shows up.

Comment: Does this work in the emulator when deploying from eclipse\adb? If it doesn't, are you sure that you've got your activity defined correctly in the manifest xml file?

Comment: I'm refering to xandy's problem. Your problem is probably because you didn't define `android.intent.action.MAIN` with `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.

Comment: @EboMike:Sounds to me like that could be Dr.Dredel's problem too.

Comment: Yeah, it was working brilliantly everywhere (even on the phone, when I ran it via Eclipse) but EboMike's solution was the righ tone. I had called my main MAIN_ACTIVITY (not realizing that it's a reserved word). I was under the impression that that if it you set it as category.LAUNCHER you could call it whatever you want, but lo and behold it HAS to be MAIN.  What's REALLY frustrating is that it worked in the emulator! Very bizarre confluence of working and not working. Anyway... Mike, post your comment as an answer, and I'll give it the thumbs up. Thanks very much!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create an activity with android.intent.action.MAIN with android.intent.category.LAUNCHER, kind of like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

For more information, see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html (under Icons and Labels).